# Segmentation fault calling std::map::clear

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, dictionary

I have been struggling with a segmentation fault for months, now I'm here to ask for help. 
The segmentation fault appears when I call the following function

```
void foo(..., std::map<MyClass*, double> & x) {
if ( !x.empty() ) x.clear();
...
}

Class A {
private:
map<MyClass*, double> _N;
public:
void f(...) {
foo(..., _N);
...
}
};

//in main routine, the function is called in a loop
A a;
while(...) {
a.f(...);
}
```

Using gdb, I tacked the error to the line calling the clear() function, it shows "double free or corruption" error, and the program aborts at calling c++/4.1.2/ext/new_allocator.h:94 delete(__P) which further calls free() from the gnu library /lib64/libc.so.6. But since the elements in the map are not allocated by new, why it still calls free() to clear it up. I would really appreciate your comments. Thank you.

Comment: The error must be elsewhere. You can call `clear()` irrespective of whether the map is empty or not anyway. Show us some more ambient code.

Comment: what happen if you pass the map by value, the program semantics would be wrong, but does it segf'?

Comment: is the object passed as parameter to `foo` allocated on the heap ? If so, is it possible that it had already been de-allocated (or moved elsewhere) before ?

Comment: Thank you guys. Actually the object passed to function foo is a member of another class. Here is a more complete description of my code, please take a look.

Comment: I think we need more code than that, to me it looks ok. A should be alive at the any point where foo is called.

Comment: Could you create a destructor for A and set a break/printf there and see if that occurs prior to segfault?

Answer (score 2):

Given that the map is owned by another object it suspiciously sounds that the map-owning object was already deleted when the clear was called.

Also note that names starting with underscore and a capital letter are reserved for the implementation - you aren't allowed to use them.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine to me.  At least with the limited context you have provided.  Usually when I run into issues like this I will simply run the valgrind memcheck tool to find the place were the first "delete" happened.  Once you know that, these issues can be pretty simple to solve.